# Import Craigslist information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the data from Craigslist into Google Sheets. I'm using `importxml` and have made some progress but can further refine the function.

A3: https://norfolk.craigslist.org/ctd/d/2011-volkswagen-jetta-only-82k-miles/6910694177.html

```
=IMPORTXML(A3,"//div[@class='mapAndAttrs']//p[@class='attrgroup'][2]")
```

This seems to return all information but I want to trim it to search for `fuel` in the result and show `gas`/`diesel`/`whatever may be`.

Comment: =IMPORTXML(A3,"//div[@class='mapAndAttrs']//p[@class='attrgroup'][2]//span[5]") wont work as some Craiglist listing have span[5] as diffrent text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A3,
 "//div[@class='mapAndAttrs']//p[@class='attrgroup'][2]")), 
 "where Col1 contains 'fuel'")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A3,
 "//div[@class='mapAndAttrs']//p[@class='attrgroup'][2]")), 
 "where Col1 contains 'fuel'"), "fuel: ", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was going for.